# Is it real that the meaning of an object changes if object that-clause becomes a subject in a passive sentence?

Tags: meaning

‘I misunderstood that the earth is flat.’

The meaning doesn’t seem to change when it comes to ‘it was misunderstood that the earth is flat.’ (The earth is in another form but it was misunderstood that the earth is flat).

But when it comes to ‘that the earth is flat was misunderstood,’ I think there’s a meaning change. (The earth is flat but it was misunderstood that the earth is in another form).

Comment: I think you can't validly say someone ***misunderstood that** the earth was flat* in English. Nor can you "passivise" that to ***it was misunderstood that** the earth was flat*. It's not that the *meaning* differs between those two; they're both just really "klunky". I'd rephrase to something like *He was **under the misunderstanding that** the earth was flat*, or ***There was a misunderstanding that** the earth was flat.* Note that I'd normally "backshift" ***is flat*** to ***was flat*** in all cases, but this isn't obligatory.

Comment: When you say that you misunderstood something, you are saying that you failed to understand something that is true. That means *misunderstood that the earth is flat* doesn't make sense. You might say *I misunderstood that the earth is round. I thought it was flat.*

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty Your answer is different from teacher Fumble.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Teacher Jack has a different opinion

Comment: @Jennifer I don't see any contradiction. It's just another viewpoint on an expression that doesn't work in English.

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty But he said misunderstand that the earth is flat but you said misunderstand that the earth is round.

Comment: Student Jennifer, On thinking further, I agree with teacher FF that *misunderstand that x* doesn't work very well, whether the clause is a true or a false statement. You can say *I didn't understand that the earth is round*, and you can say *I misunderstood the shape of the earth*, but *misunderstand* doesn't fit well with that kind of clause as direct object.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty Teacher J, I rewrote the question. Please come here. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/578636/that-clause-as-a-subject-and-an-object

Comment: @Jennifer I agree with FF that it doesn't work as a passive expression, either. It would be said *It was not understood that the earth was flat.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131526/discussion-between-jack-oflaherty-and-jennifer).

Comment: @Jack O’Flaherty I chatted.